# Changing "Project Url" causes ASP.Net Web app to not be debuggable

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET Web Application project that I am using to host a WCF Data Services (OData) project.

I went and changed the url from:

> http://localhost/MyProject

to

> http://localhost/v1/MyProject

after I did that I created a Virtual Directory for the new project URL.

Now when I run I get this error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See help for common configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information.

I clicked help but it was no help (was IIS 6 level instructions, I have IIS 7).  I did some googling and it was all fairly generic responses.

How can I get this working again?  (Aside from revert to my old Url.  Reverting works but I changed it for a very good reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to my website in IIS and add a folder under it called **v1**.  After I did that it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your virtual directory need to point to the same scr directory you were originally debugging against.

Also, make sure the virtual directory is configured for Windows Authentication, which is required for debugging.

Comment: Any idea how to do those things?  I looked at the "View Virtual Directories" action for my site and there is nothing there (no virtual directories listed).  But Visual studio thinks one has been created.  Why does it think that?  Where can I edit it?  And how do I config the virtual directory for windows authentication?